# Closing app via keyboard shortcut — should there be a confirmation dialogue?

Tags: confirmation

There are many ways to close apps: mouse-and-click on an 'x' somewhere, choose "Quit" as a menu option, keyboard shortcuts (ctrl-w, cmd-q, alt-f4 etc.)

I notice some apps I use ask me "Are you sure you want to exit?" when I try to close them.

What are the UX guidelines as to when there should be an "Are you sure you want to exit?" confirmation dialogue?

Comment: I understand your question is not an exact duplicate, but I believe the answers are equally applicable here. I was about to answer in the exact same way for this question. I don't think it matters much what the trigger is, as long as you warn the user when closure can be "costly" (either costing the user loss of data, time, frustration, uptime, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how much thing get lost by quitting the app? For example when I opened a new tab on browser I don't expect to see a confirmation dialog. But when 10 tabs are open I am pretty sure I want to keep them and don't want to lose anything right now. Now confirmation dialog makes sense.
**So think the right answers is it depends!**
Consider this too: how hard is recovering to where I was if I accidentally quit the app?